# Asymptotic Analysis of coefficients of $\mathrm{e}^{x+x^2/2}$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Let $a_n=[x^n]\mathrm{e}^{x+x^2/2}.$   How does one show that $$ a_n \sim\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} n^{-(n+1)/2}\mathrm{e}^{-n/2+\sqrt n -1/4}?$$

I'd also appreciate references illustrating relevant techniques.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x) = e^{x+x^2/2}
$$
is the exponential generating function for the number of involutions on finite sets.

An analytic derivation of the asymptotic formula
$$
[x^n]f(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} n^{-(n+1)/2} e^{n/2+\sqrt{n}-1/4}\left(1+O\left(n^{-1/5}\right)\right)
$$
can be found on pages 558-560 in Flajolet and Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics* ([freely available here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)).  Flajolet also cites volume 3 of Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*, which he says contains a derivation of the bound through the use of the explicit formula
$$
[x^n]f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{(n-2k)!2^k k!}.
$$

Comment: @Yiorgos, I like the regular typeface for $e$, no need to change it :)

Comment: Ok - understood!